# Access object in Angular passed by Spring's ModelAndView

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-mvc, atlassian-connect

I am trying to set up an Atlassian Connect addon for Jira with [atlassian-connect-spring-boot](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/atlassian-connect-spring-boot) and Angular 4.

For rendering the view, I have to define a rest endpoint which returns a `ModelAndView`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView helloWorld(@AuthenticationPrincipal AtlassianHostUser hostUser) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.setViewName("index");
    model.addObject("hostUser", hostUser);
    return model;
}
```

This will render my frontend, so the `index.html`. This works perfectly fine, except I do not know how I can access the object `hostUser` in Angular now.

Is this even possible, if yes how? If not, how can I pass an object from the spring backend to the angular frontend without having to make a custom rest call (due to the fact that Atlassian Connect handles the authentication by calling the rest endpoints itself)

I contacted Atlassian already, but I have not received an answer yet.

Answer (score -1):

You seem to have been confused with server and client side technologies.

Assuming you have configured `InternalResourceViewResolver` which is `JSP+JSTL` ViewResolver your controller will return a JSP file. If you are using `Thymeleaf` template then your view resolver will change accordingly.

Angular is client side part and nothing to do with server side presentation. If you are using angular you should create spring boot webservices to get the data and render it in accordingly in the UI.

Look at below blog for example -
https://spring.io/blog/2015/08/19/migrating-a-spring-web-mvc-application-from-jsp-to-angularjs . Specially the "Considerations when moving from JSP to AngularJS" part.

Don't try to mix both :)